# Como remover bordas e deixar o background de uma janela Modal transparente

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma janela modal que exibe um Spinner para indicar o carregamento de uma page. O problema é essa modal precisa ficar sem as bordas e com fundo transparente. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div id="modalSpinner" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="loader vertical-align-middle loader-circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode retirar alterando as propriedades da classe `.modal-content`:

```
#modalSpinner .modal-content{
   -webkit-box-shadow: none; // retira a sombra
   box-shadow: none; // retira a sombra
   background: transparent; // fundo transparente
   border: none; //  retira a borda
}
```

Isso irá alterar apenas a modal da `div#modalSpinner`, sem afetar as outas modais, se houverem.

Se seu CSS for carregado antes do CSS do Bootstrap, haverá necessidade de colocar `!important` nas propriedades:

```
#modalSpinner .modal-content{
   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; // retira a sombra
   box-shadow: none !important; // retira a sombra
   background: transparent !important; // fundo transparente
   border: none !important; //  retira a borda
}
```

> Pelo que pude perceber pela imagem, a modal nem tem borda, apenas o
>   fundo branco e um sombreamento. Talvez não haja necessidade das linhas
>   `box-shadow`.

Comment: muito, muito, muito obrigado cara!!!!!!!!!!! Funcionou 100%